# using df.apply and str.contains('value', case =False)

Tags: python, pandas

Data:

```
A     |    B   |    C    
========================
Value | Fred   |    0
foo   | Jim    |    1
Value | Bob    |    2
```

I have written a method:

```
def is_value(df):
    if df['A'].str.contains('value', case=False):
        b='X'
        return b
```

I call it with:

```
df['B'] = df.apply(is_value, axis=1)
```

and get the following error:

```
AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'str'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Is this allowed in apply?

It works with this idiom:

```
df = df.loc[df['A'].str.contains('Value', case=False) & df['C'] !=0]
df['A'] = 'X'
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: How can this be made to work like a SQL update statement?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best is not use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) if it is not necessary, because obviously it is slower.

I think you can use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
print df['A'].str.contains('value', case=False)
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: A, dtype: bool

df['B'] = df.mask(df['A'].str.contains('value', case=False), 'X')
print df
       A    B  C
0  Value    X  0
1    foo  Jim  1
2  Value    X  2
```

Another solution with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[ df['A'].str.contains('value', case=False), 'B'] = 'X'
print df
       A    B  C
0  Value    X  0
1    foo  Jim  1
2  Value    X  2
```

EDIT:

It seems you need add filtering values not equal `0` in column `C`:

```
print (df['A'].str.contains('value', case=False)) & (df['C'] !=0)
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool

df['B'] = df.mask((df['A'].str.contains('value', case=False)) & (df['C'] !=0), 'X')
print df
       A      B  C
0  Value  Value  0
1    foo    foo  1
2  Value      X  2


df.loc[(df['A'].str.contains('value', case=False)) & (df['C'] !=0) , 'B'] = 'X'
print df
       A      B  C
0  Value  Value  0
1    foo    foo  1
2  Value      X  2
```

Comment: Please check solution, maybe some improvement is necessary.

Comment: @jezreail I am trying to update column 'B' 
    UPDATE df
    SET B='X'
    WHERE A='Value' AND 'C' != 0